# Forgiveness,masturbation, porn

Tags: halal-haram, allah, punishment, forgiveness, masturbation

Aoa my name is ahmed and i am a muslim boy i was addicted to masturbation but just got rid of it it was terrible but now i want to ask forgiveness from Allah i can't talk to anyone in my family about it cause i am ashamed so i heard about a punishment of masturbation in the hear after that my hands will become pregnant but i don't want pregnant hands or any punishment like that cause i am scared, so if i ask for forgiveness is it Possible that i will be forgiven and not get this punishment?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such **Hadith** of your hands “becoming pregnant” in the after life due to masturbation.
I have never heard such a thing from any sheikh except for this article talking about this Turkish man claiming masturbation would cause pregnant hands.

However, on the day of judgement, your eyes, hands, tongue, etc. will speak on your behalf for whatever sin you committed with them. So with masturbation, if you don’t repent, they will speak on your behalf.

> “On this Day We will seal their mouths, their hands will speak to Us,
> and their feet will testify to what they used to commit.” 
>  Yasin 36:65

If you repent sincerely to Allah, Allah will forgive you.

> “Verily, He is One Who forgives (accepts repentance), the Most Merciful.” 
>  The Cow 2:37

> “Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful.”’ 
>  The Groups 39:53

Comment: So even if it is true is it Possible to not get this punishment and be forgiven if i ask Allah for forgiveness

Comment: Please reply may Allah bless you

Comment: @Ahmed are you even reading what I’ve wrote? Yes. If you repent, Allah will forgive you. Why would you still be punished for something Allah has already forgiven you for?

Comment: Thank you brother may Allah forgive us all ameen

Comment: @Ahmed Please upvote and/or check my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: My feedback has been recorded

Comment: InShaAllah we meet in jannah

Comment: It says i need 15 reputation i don't have 15 but when i do i will upvote

Comment: @Ahmed okay Inshallah.